# Puting other link on the flash element with internal link inside

Tags: hyperlink, flash

How to change a link inside the flash element? I have SWF file with set a link inside and I want to change to mine on the website. This thing I need to control the advertisment system.

Trying this, but not working:

```
<style>
#content {    
position: absolute;
z-index:2; 
} 
#flash {   
position: relative;
z-index:1; 
} 
</style>

<div id="content" onclick="window.open('http://mylink.com','_blank');"><img src="no" width="100" height="100" border="0"></div>

<div id="flash"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://active.macromedia.com/flash4/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0" width="100" height="100">
<param name="movie" value="111.swf">
<param name="play" value="true">
<param name="loop" value="true">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="111.swf" play="true" loop="true" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" width="100" height="100"></embed>
</object></div>
```

Right now found this exapmle:

```
<div style="border: #FF9900 3px dotted; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
     <object id="swf">
        <embed src="/uploads/storys_files/2006.03.15_15.55.30/123.swf" loop="true" quality="high" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" height="200" width="400">
     </object><a href="#"><img src="http://yapro.ru/uploads/users/1/2010/12/16/782d4b5d3c55bdc50619b8aa141b4ecc.gif" height="170" width="350" style="border: #99FF00 3px dotted; position: relative; top: -190px; left: 20px; margin-bottom: -170px; z-index: 1;"></a>
</div>
```

But you need everytime to put top, left, margin-bottom parameters. Can someone modify it to make working correct without pointing top, left, margin-bottom parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.FLA` file to edit the source and recompile, unless the SWF is XML-driven.  But it doesn't sound like it's something you built.

Here's how you can do a div overlay...

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
  <div id="content">Insert content here</div>
  <div id="flash">Insert flash here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#content {
    background-color:#0099ff;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:100px;
    z-index:2;
}
#flash {
    background-color:#ccff33;
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: @TNC what if I don't have that FLA file? Is there any way how to change a link or put my link on SWF file?

Comment: Not really, at least not through flash.  You could overlay the SWF with HTML

Comment: @TNC executng your example, flash and content layers displayed separately, not one-in-one ((

Comment: yeah, I'm not gonna built it all for you :)  I got you started and it looks like you got what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decision how to put any link on the SWF (Flash) file ignoring its internal programm link:

```
<div style="position:relative;">

<div style="z-index:822; position:absolute; width:inherit; height:inherit; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;">
<img src="transparent.gif" width="100" height="100" onclick="location.href='http://webproverka.com';">
</div>

<object >
<embed src="111.swf" loop="true" wmode="opaque" quality="high"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" height="100" width="100">
</object>


</div>
```